# loop rand(), on next rand() don't use previous?

Tags: c++, random, ctime

I need two random numbers each loop, but cannot use the previous loop's random numbers. I'm lost, I've searched and don't know what to do. Please help! I've put my code below. So, what I need, specifically, is to generate two random numbers stored in n1 & n2. Then, on the next loop, not use those previous numbers. However, it is okay to use them after they have not been used twice in a row.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //declare variables
    int numAttempts = 3;
    int response;
    char playAgain;
    int points;
    bool previousAnswer;
    srand(time(0));

    //Welcome user to the program and explain the rules
    cout << "\nWelcome! This is the Multiplication Practice Game!" << endl
    << "A multiplication problem will be presented which you must solve." << endl << endl
    << "THESE ARE THE RULES:" << endl
    << "*You start with 3 lives." << endl
    << "*Each correct answer earns you 5 points!" << endl
    << "*An incorrect answer results in 1 life lost." << endl
    << "*If you're incorrect but within 5 of the answer:" << endl
    << "\t-you are granted another attempt" << endl
    << "\t-you earn 3 points if correct" << endl
    << "\t-you lose a life if incorrect" << endl
    << "*Once you lose all of your lives, it's game over!" << endl << endl
    << "Good luck, let's begin..." << endl << endl;

    //Do while numAttempts is not equal to 0
    do{
            //Random numbers for n1 and n2
            int n1 = rand() % 13;
            int n2 = rand() % 13;

            //Present the problem and prompt for response
            cout << "Answer the problem: ";
            cout << n1 << "*"<< n2 << ": ";
            cin >> response;

            //If response is correct, congratulate
            if(response == n1*n2)
            {
                cout << "CORRECT, great job. Keep going! \n\n";
                points += 5;
                previousAnswer = true;
            }

            //If response is not correct and lives are not equal to 0
            if((response != (n1*n2)) && (numAttempts != 0))
            {
                //If response is not within 5 of the correct answer, no second chance and subtract 1 from numAttempts
                if((response > (n1*n2)+5) || (response < (n1*n2)-5) || (previousAnswer != true))
                {
                    cout << "That answer is incorrect." << endl;
                    numAttempts -= 1;
                    previousAnswer = false;
                    cout << "You have " << numAttempts << " lives remaining" << endl << endl;
                }

                //If response is within 5 of correct answer and previousAnswer is true, offer second attempt
                if(response <= ((n1*n2)+5) && (response >= (n1*n2)-5) && (previousAnswer == true))
                {
                    cout << "So close, try once more: ";
                    cin >> response;
                    if(response == n1 * n2)
                    {
                        cout << "CORRECT, great job. Keep going! \n\n";
                        points +=3;
                        previousAnswer = true;
                    }

                    //If answer is still incorrect, subtract 1 from numAttempts
                    else{
                    cout << "Sorry, that answer is still incorrect" << endl;
                    numAttempts -= 1;
                    previousAnswer = false;
                    cout << "You have " << numAttempts << " lives remaining" << endl << endl;
                    }
                }
            }


            //If user runs out of lives, notify and ask if they would like to play again
            if (0 == numAttempts)
            {
                cout << "You're all out of lives!" << endl
                << "Your total score is " << points << ", great job!" << endl
                << "Would you like to play again? Y/N: ";
                cin >> playAgain;
                if('y' == tolower(playAgain))
                {
                    cout << "\nGreat! Let's try again! Good luck!" << endl;
                    numAttempts += 3;
                    cout << "Let's begin..." << endl << endl;
                }else{
                cout << "\nThanks for playing, see you next time!" << endl;
                }
            }
      }while(numAttempts != 0); //ends loop if attempts are equal to 0


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep the previous iteration's random values in separate variables (defined outside the do loop), and compare them against the new ones. If they're the same use `continue` to loop again and pick two new ones.

Comment: Thank you! I just made an if statement in my loop that would continue if the conditions were met. Awesome.

Comment: To indicate that your problem is solved, accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to perform a random choice without repeating is to keep a list of numbers in a random order, one entry for each number in your range. Then you just take the one at the front of the list, use it, and move it to a later position.

In your case you would move it to at least one away from the front (after removing it) so that the next number at the front won't be the same as the old front.

Example:

initial list:

6, 5, 10, 1, 0, 11, 8, 12, 4, 2, 3, 7, 9

Take the first number and remove from list.

list is now:

5, 10, 1, 0, 11, 8, 12, 4, 2, 3, 7, 9

Insert the number in a random position that is not the front.

list is now:

5, 10, 1, 6, 0, 11, 8, 12, 4, 2, 3, 7, 9

Comment: Thanks for the input. I ended up just creating an if statement in the loop that would continue if the previous vars were the same.

Comment: Oh okay, gotcha. I'm new.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `randomize();` before your `rand()%13` then program will generate every time random numbers and will not repeat ..